# play a video as blob url from a server

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

I am trying to play an mp4 video as blob url and I don't want the uses to be able to see the video url

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
     <script src='https://cdn.jwplayer.com/libraries/ge6vrLRb.js'></script>
     <script>jwplayer.key='******';</script> </head> <body>
     <script>
         var url = 'mysite/1.mp4'
         let blob =  fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());
         console.log(blob);
     </script>
     <div id="player">Loading the player...</div>
     <script>
         // Setup the player
         const player = jwplayer('player').setup({
             file: blob
         });
     </script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: FYI, users can still view the source of your page and see the URL that you've hardcoded. They can also watch network traffic and see the request for that URL.

Comment: yes thats true but this will stop hotlinking

Comment: No, hotlinking is when a site pulls a resource from a different domain. Your solution won't prevent somebody from determining the URL and linking to it from their site. The only way to stop hotlinking is to detect that the referrer is from a different domain and refuse the request.